# HTTP 404 error - in simple Struts2 application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2, http-status-code-404

A simple hello world application is showing http-404 error.

I am using the tools below:

1) Eclipse Luna 4.4

2) Apcache tomcat 7.0

3) JDK 7

---

**Application structure**

[image: My application structure looks like this]

### Am I missing any jar files ???

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Simple form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Myaction" method="get">
<input type="text" name="t1"><br>
<input type="submit" value="GO">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Myaction.java**

```
package com.Action;

public class Myaction {
String t1;

public String getT1(){
    return t1;
}
public void setT1(String t1) {
    this.t1 = t1;
}
public String execute(){
    System.out.println(t1);
    return "success";
}
}
```

---

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">

    <action name="Myaction" class="com.Action.Myaction" method="execute">
        <result name="success" type="redirect">/Welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

---

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>Welcome -> <s:property value="t1"/> </label>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

The Markers showing this warnings

`<s:property>` -- is not found in build path

Also, server showing the error: resource not available
how to solve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: To solve this error we need to know what resource is requested.

Comment: You have *a lot* of **garbage** in your classpath. `Struts2-core-2.0.1.2.jar`, for example, along with all the rest. Please check carefully your classpath, fix it, clean everything, and retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is :

In the web project

1) Go to Build Path-configure build path

2) If you are using external JRE then it will give Http 404 error, so I used JDK 
i.e. Add library- Libraries- Installed JREs

3) Give path of JDK. (We have to use internal JRE)

4) Finish

5) Refresh the project

And it will work..

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting struts-.dtd from strut2.core-version.jar into WEB-INF/classes & re-run the project.

Comment: Still showing error: SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: >org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Comment: even though i am using struts 2.3.20 version which is greater than 2.0

Comment: are you sure these jars are going to lib folder in tomcat too?

Comment: you can also see in the screenshot you uploaded that jars are not being exported. So you need to resolve that issue & you'll be fine.

Comment: For now,  you can manually copy the jars and paste them into tomcat/webapps/your_app/WEB_INF/lib folder. This way we can be sure if this is the exact problem.